# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for Rocket chat integration

Tags: php, angularjs

I have implemented the rocket chat with my application. So following are the details which I have done on local system:

1. Rocket chat installed on: `http://192.168.10.180:3000`
2. My application installed on: `http://192.168.10.180`

And I am sending the origin header as `http://192.168.10.180` while I am accessing rocket chat server.

And it's working good in local environment.

But the same thing I have done on my server as.

1. Rocket installed on: `http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com:3000`
2. My application is on: `http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com`

and I am sending the origin as: `http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com`.

But on this I am getting the following error.

```
Failed to load http://app.apiptl.staging.edubold.com/app_dev.php    
/api/rocetchat/authuser: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a
  value 'http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com:3000' that is not equal to the 
  supplied origin. Origin 'http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com' is 
   therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Rocket installed on: http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com:3000  . no need to specifies port 3000. put only 1:Rocket installed on: http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com

Comment: what you mean it will work only 3000 port by default?

Comment: on which port it will work i m not sure but on server no need to specifies port

Comment: it works on 3000 by default

Answer (score 0):

I'd question this statement:

> I am sending the origin as: http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com.

because it tells otherwise:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a
>     value 'http://app.ptl.staging.edubold.com:3000' that is not equal to the 
>     supplied origin.

So you have to remove the port from the header value, to make it fit.